# Run script through word length, not through characters count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I only found a way to count the characters of a content, but what I need is the word length. For example, at **words of 20 characters** the css do something, but **not if the 20 characters are more then one word** ...

That´s what I try, but it counts characters ;(

```
var s = $(".text").html();

if (s.split(' ').length > 20) {
   $(".text").css({
      'background-color' : '#F00',
      'font-weight' : 'bold'
   });
}
```

Is that possible with jquery?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you mean that you only want to apply this CSS styling to individual words that are longer than 20 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the length of the single word, but apply the CSS rules to the whole text. You will need to separate the text by words, and apply the style to some of them.

```js
var container = $("#myText");

var words = container.text().split(' ');
container.empty();

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    if (words[i].length > 20)
    {
        $("<span/>").text(words[i] + " ").addClass('longword').appendTo(container);
    } else {
        container.html(container.html() + words[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

```css
.longword {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myText">
  Here is the simple text which contains some very long words like pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism or antidisestablishmentarianism.
</div>
```

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
Here is the simple text which contains some very long words 
like <span class="longword">pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism</span> or 
<span class="longword">antidisestablishmentarianism</span>.
```

Comment: Big thx for support, that´s absolutly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

You are basically counting the words now. In order to check if there are words longer than 20 characters you have to do something like this:

```
s.split(' ').some(function(a) {return a.length > 20})
```

[The definition of some can be found here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0):

```
s.split(" ") will return you an array of strings.
```

just change the line

if (str.split(' ').length > 20)

to

if (str.split(' ')[0].length > 20)

Comment: Also thx for support - I try this way, but at me it doesn´t work.